# C++ elegant way for prioritized search in STL container

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I wrote a small function whose aim is to go through a list of elements in order, do some checks on the hashmap value of it and if they pass, return it.

```
QString ElementContainer::getPreferedAvailableElement() const
{
    QStringList preferred_priority = { A, B, C, D, E };
    foreach(QString element, preferred_priority){
        Element*  data = m_hashmap.value(element, nullptr);
        if(data && data->isReady()){
            return element;
        }
    }
    return QString("");
}
```

I know that those functional kind of std functions should not be forced no matter if it makes sense or not. I am just curious how you can transform this and if it maybe is more verbose.

Comment: Could you please reformulate your question? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve, what you've done so far and what is the problem.

Comment: You appear to be writing code in [tag:C++03], a Qt-variant of it (with various macros).  Is this a constraint on a solution?

Comment: @Hack06 what I try to achieve: find the first element of the hashmap matching the isReady criteria going through in order of the preferred_priority list. What I have done so far is layed out above, the naive way of doing this. My question is if there is a more readable, verbose, concise way of writing this.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont it is indeed a Qt Variant with C++11. The elements in the QStringList are not macros but constants. Should not matter I guess.

Comment: @Curunir `foreach` is a QT macro, for example.  In C++11 there is no need for it: `for(QString element:preferred_priority)` is a macro-less example.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Right, forgot about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::find_if` like this:

```
QString ElementContainer::getPreferedAvailableElement() const
{
   QStringList preferred_priority = { A, B, C, D, E };
   auto it = std::find_if(preferred_priority.begin(), 
      preferred_priority.end(), 
      [this](const QString & element)
   { 
      Element* data = m_hashmap.value(element, nullptr);
      return (data && data->isReady());
   });

   if (it != preferred_priority.end())
   {
      return *it;
   }

   return QString("");
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I did not have a clue what to search for in the std namespace. Thanks.